# Creating a bifurcation diagram in python

Tags: python, chaos

I am trying to come up with a code that will allow me to plot a diagram for period doubling bifurcation.

I am using the equation `x = rx − 1(1 − x)`, and am trying to model it with r values from 0.5 to 4.  Here is code that I am working with

```
startr = 0.5
finalr = 4
max_time = 200
x = [0.1]
r= np.linspace(.5,4,200)

for n in range(0,200):

    x = np.append(r * x[n] * (1-x[n]))


plt.plot(x, label='x');
plt.xlabel('t');
```

This keeps getting kicked out

```
TypeError: append() missing 1 required positional argument: 'values'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The are the two absolutely necessary arguments for `numpy.append()`, taken from the [Numpy reference.](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.append.html)

> **arr** : array_like Values are appended to a copy of this array.
>
> **values** :
>   array_like These values are appended to a copy of arr. It must be of
>   the correct shape (the same shape as arr, excluding axis). If axis is
>   not specified, values can be any shape and will be flattened before
>   use.

Therefore, try using

```
np.append(x, r * x[n] * (1-x[n]))
```

inside your loop.

Comment: thanks! It's giving me a new error at that exact line -IndexError: invalid index to scalar variable.

Comment: I am not getting an error, when I run your code with my fix implemented. Perhaps you might have to ask a new question with your updated piece of code in order to address the new issue that you are having with your code

Answer (score 0):

> **Logistic Map**
> *Save file and run, png image file of graph will save in the same folder*

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

Many =50000

x = np.random.rand(Many)
r = np.linspace(0,4.0, num= Many)

for i in range(1, 54):
    x_a = 1-x
    Data= np.multiply(x,r)
    Data= np.multiply(Data, x_a)
    x = Data

    plt.title(r'Logistic map: $x_{n+1} = r x_{n} (1-x_{n}).$  n = '+ str(i) )
    plt.ylabel('x-Random number')
    plt.xlabel('r-Rate')
    
    plt.scatter(r, Data, s=0.1, c='k')
    plt.show()
    plt.savefig(str(i) + " Logistic Map.png", dpi = 300)
    plt.clf()
```